# cloudsqladmin keeping CloudSQL instance always on?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

My PostgreSQL instance of Google CLoudSQL is somehow kept always on (according to the expense reports). Naturally, I want it turn off when it's not needed to reduce the charges.

I see that it always has 4 connections from cloudsqladmin:

[image: Number of connections. Blue lines - cloudsqladmin, orange - requests from my services]

And those connections generate something like a heartbeat at 2.5 requests per second, way more than my own services:

[image: Transactions per second]

Point-in-time recovery is turned off in the settings.

Is this normal? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud SQL, much like VM's provided by Compute Engine, are managed infrastructure. [A Cloud SQL instance doesn't shut off unless you tell it to shut it off](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance).

The 4 connections marked as "sqladmin" are used by the Cloud SQL service to perform administration tasks and monitoring. They are using minimal resources, but are used for things like creating a database via the API (or GUI) or generating the graphs you are looking at.